# Another for loop question: efficiency versus readability

Tags: performance-tuning, coding-style

I have some **sorted** data:

```
data = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 15}, 10]]
```

and I want to generate a `duplicate` array where a counter is increased each time we discover a different element in the `data` array. By example:

```
data:      {0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 11, 14}
duplicate: {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6,  6,  7}
```

In a procedural programming approach, a possible procedure would be:

```
createDuplicateForLoop[data_List] := 
  Block[{dup, count, n},
   n = Length[data];
   If[n == 0, Return[{}];];
   count = 1;
   dup = ConstantArray[count, n];
   For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
    If[data[[i - 1]] == data[[i]], 
      dup[[i]] = count, 
      dup[[i]] = ++count];
    ];
   Return[dup];
  ];
```

However in MMA loops are not efficient. That's why I tried to find an equivalent solution using built-in MMA functions and more in a functional style. I got this:

```
createDuplicate[data_List] := 
  Block[{dup}, 
   dup = Tally[Range[Length[data]], (data[[#1]] == data[[#2]]) &];
   dup = Flatten[
     MapThread[
      ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, 
      {Range[Length[dup]], Part[dup, All, 2]}
     ]
   ];
   Return[dup];
  ];
```

Now benchmarking:

```
n = 100000;
data = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 15}, n]];
t0 = First@Timing[r0 = createDuplicateForLoop[data];]
t1 = First@Timing[r1 = createDuplicate[data];]
Print["For loop is ", t0/t1, "x slower"]
r0 == r1
```

I get:

```
0.694893
0.022270
For loop is 31.20x slower
True
```

So clearly the "for loop" solution is **slower**, however I find it much **more readable** than the version using the `Tally` function.

**Question:** I am curious to know if someone has an idea for a solution keeping not only efficiency but also readability?

---

**A summary of the comments:**

```
n = 100000;
data = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 15}, n]];
t0 = First@Timing[r0 = createDuplicateForLoop[data];]
t1 = First@Timing[r1 = createDuplicate[data];]
t2 = First@Timing[r2 = 1 + ArrayComponents@data;]
t3 = First@
  Timing[r3 = Accumulate[Prepend[Unitize[Differences[data]], 1]];]
Print["For loop is ", t0/t1, "x slower"]
r0 == r1

0.590431
0.022422
0.021350
0.003437
For loop is 26.33x slower
True
```

Thanks to Kuba & Henrik, I learned a lot!

Comment: `1 + ArrayComponents @ data;` let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: @Kuba Awesome! I did not know this function! If you put this in an anwser I will be happy to accept it. I feel a little embarrassed with my long question now :-/

Comment: @Kuba I have not seen it was already answered. So I will delete it, is it ok for you?

Comment: I did also not know this function; I'd rather have used `Accumulate[Prepend[Unitize[Differences[data]], 1]]`... which turns out to produce the same result 10 times faster.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks again for answering my second (and last, I promise!) question about loops.

Comment: @PicaudVincent it is fine to be a duplicate :) it is a roadsign for a future visitors.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Linked topic extends to unsorted arrays so if you think it is worth to optimize solutions for OP's specific case I am fine with reopening.

Comment: @Kuba ok, thanks. My proposition to upvote/accept your answer still holds :)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher your solution is 10x faster than Kuba one. That is a surprise to see such a difference. Again, thanks, I you want to write an answer I will be happy to accept it too

Comment: Well, `ArrayComponents` can do more than the code that I posted; but as often, a specialized approach can be faster. My approach utilizes the fact that due to preordering, the resulting array is monotonically increasing. This avoids all lookups and thus allows for using vectorized approaches.

Comment: Another solution using Split: `Split[data] // MapIndexed[ConstantArray[First@#2, Length[#1]] &] // Flatten`

Comment: @sakra thanks I will add it to the bench but tomorrow, once I will have access to the same computer